# How do you get the X value in KMeans clustering in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I'm a complete beginner for KMeans. How do you understand what X value to take? I have a dataframe with several rows and columns. I don't know how I can take one specific X value.

I cant substitute the entire dataframe. 
eg:

```
df = pd.read_csv("cereal.csv")
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4)
kmeans.fit(X) ## How do I get this X?
```

Comment: Where did you get this example? Link here and I'll take a look

Comment: try this x_predicted = kmeans.labels_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`X` is basically all the values from your dataframe which in this case is `df`.

For example:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

X = df.values.astype(np.float)
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 4).fit(X)
```

To see the labels assigned, you can now do:

```
predicted_values = kmeans.labels_
```

---

**Note:**

You may have to perform data cleaning and remove features prior to passing it to the KMeans algorithm. In other words, some columns can be removed for example, ID if you have one.

If any of your columns have `string` values, they need to be encoded into a `numerical` format. For example, you cannot pass values like `high` or `low`, you need to encode them into `0` or `1`.